# How to add custom attributes to head tag in js Fiddle?

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle, fiddle

After the recent uplift of js Fiddle, where can we include custom attributes(like ng-app) to head tag in JS Fiddle HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the top right corners of the various sections (take a look at the screenshots)

[image]
[image]